# Deployment from IIS Express to IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I apologize if this question is too generic but I would like to know is there a procedure to apply web.config settings 1 to 1 when deploying to IIS ?
Because I have a solution (ASP.NET MVC 3) that works without any errors from IIS Expess and Visual Studio but when I deploy to IIS many functionality fails mainly file download and 404 errors on controller action calls. IIS 8.5 that runs on Windows 2012 Server.

Thanks

Comment: Your web.config should be deployed along with everything else making it 1-1, aside from other higher level server settings.  A couple things to look for: make sure MVC is installed on the server and make sure your virtual directory is set up as an application.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the "Publish" feature in Visual studio to deploy the web application on the web server. This way VS will take care of the all the required files and everything. 
1. Create a publish profile in Visual studio based on how you can access your web server i.e IIS (like through file shared, ftp)
2. Then use this profile to publish your project.

Hope this helps.
Please let me know if you need step by step guidance to do this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that is the way I do the deploy. I have created publishing profile that points directly to the web site in IIS. First VS build solution then it give some kind of preview with changes and that part goes well. Then I guess it copies files and start browser with URL to my site. Problem is that after deployment from VS some parts of application (not all) make problems.

Comment: I have noticed though that in some of the build step he creates some kind of ACL (Access Control List), it pop up in output during build. Is there maybe a difference if I just publish to zip then unpack and copy directly. This is not preferred but if it work I can settle with that workaround.

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshot of the ACL messages coming in the output during build process? Also sometimes we publish the project in the local folder and then copy the contents manually on the server. You can try it and see if it works. It is not preferred but in some projects where there is manual deployment process people use this approach as this way they have the control on the folders and see what is being published and deployed.

Comment: "VS will take care of all the required files and everything". If you don't work for Microsoft on this product, I think such a claim can be a little bit more than the truth. And if you work on such a product, you should be able to point out the limitation.

Comment: hahaha i don't work for microsoft..the intent was that visual studio publishing will compile and create the folders which are required on the web server. In the project there are many files which are not required but i have seen people who simple copies everything on the server..yes there are people who don't publish but just build and manually copy all the files.